# Create a bootable USB with Windows installer for Yosemite?

Tags: bootcamp, windows, usb, startup, server.app

I'm having trouble creating a bootable USB for my mac.
I have an iMac, and I'm wanting to install a copy of Windows Server 2008 x86 onto it. I've tried BootCamp, but I'm getting errors when selecting the ISO because it is "not Windows 7 or later".

Does anyone have any idea how I could create a USB that I can boot on my Mac, with my Windows Server 2008 ISO?

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to burn a bootable USB stick (taken from the Ubuntu website):

1. Open the Terminal (in /Applications/Utilities/ or query Terminal in Spotlight).
2. Convert the .iso file to .img using the convert option of hdiutil e.g., `hdiutil convert -format UDRW -o ~/path/to/target.img ~/path/to/windows.iso`
   Note: OS X tends to put the .dmg ending on the output file automatically.
3. Run `diskutil list` to get the current list of devices.
4. Insert your flash media.
5. Run `diskutil list` again and determine the new device node assigned to your flash media (e.g. /dev/disk2).
6. Run `diskutil unmountDisk /dev/diskN` (replace N with the disk number from the last command; in the previous example, N would be 2).
7. Execute `sudo dd if=/path/to/downloaded.img of=/dev/rdiskN bs=1m` (replace /path/to/downloaded.img with the path where the image file is located; for example, ./windows.img or ./ubuntu.dmg). Using /dev/rdisk instead of /dev/disk may be faster. If you see the error dd: Invalid number '1m', you are using GNU dd. Use the same command but replace bs=1m with bs=1M. If you see the error dd: /dev/diskN: Resource busy, make sure the disk is not in use. Start the 'Disk Utility.app' and unmount (don't eject) the drive.
8. Run `diskutil eject /dev/diskN` and remove your flash media when the command completes.
9. Restart your Mac and press alt/option key while the Mac is restarting to choose the USB stick.

Comment: Tried this method and was very hopeful. Everything looked good, until I rebooted, and the Mac still couldn't see the USB at the boot device selection screen. Guess I'll just have to source some more DVDs tommorow!

Answer (score -1):

According to the Ubuntu site, you can do the following:

1. Launch Disk Utility (Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility).
2. Insert your blank CD/DVD. Drag and drop your .iso file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now both the blank disc and the .iso should be listed.
3. Select the .iso file, and click on the Burn button in the
   toolbar.

   [image: macosx_disk-utility]

   Ensure that the "Verify burned data" checkbox is ticked (you may need to click on the disclosure triangle to see the checkbox).
4. Click on Burn. The data will be burned and verified.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm trying to create a bootable usb because 1. I'm fed up of burning DVDs because I can't burn them again, 2. I don't actually have any DVDs that I can burn to left!

Comment: Yeah, it makes shure its a bootable. It takes a few steps. But i can boot any linux version i want from usb via this tutorial. Done the same with windows 7, vista and xp. I run all opperating systems :)

Comment: Ah okay, sounds good. Would I be able to boot it from a mac if I tried that?

Comment: Yup, have a imac an mac pro running linux dual boot with osx. I used to have osx dualboot with windows. But wanted an alternative to bootcamp. This was my sollution. I was used to bios from windows haha. This made more scense installing an os than bootcamp! Hope it helps you out. And otherwize ill post the exact link tomorrow!

Comment: Thanks a lot man! I found the post I think you're referring to, I will give it a go now!

Comment: Cool good luck mate!